# Windows 8 Httpclient basic authentcation

Tags: dotnet-httpclient

I am new to this forum.

I am trying to do Basic authentication using Httclient for my Windows app.

```
var handler2 = new HttpClientHandler
{
Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)
};
var httpClient2 = new HttpClient(handler2);
httpClient2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-Agent", "authentication.cs");
var response2 = httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

I have 2 questions:

I need to add header content type and user-agent. Dont know how to add them. Could someone help me out.

In response i am getting null values. Any idea why?

Regards,

TM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the user agent header by doing

```
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("authentication.cs"));
```

You can't add Content-Type to the default request headers because you can only set Content-Type when you are sending some Content using a PUT or a POST.
I'm guessing you want to set the Accept header like this:

```
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

---

Update:  Without my own account, this is as far as I can go.

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InitHttpClient();

    }

    private void InitHttpClient() {
        var username = "youremail@somewhere.com";
        var password = "yourharvestpassword";
        String authparam = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authparam);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("MyHarvestClient", "1.0"));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {

        _httpClient.GetAsync("https://yoursubdomain.harvestapp.com/projects")
            .ContinueWith(t => HandleResponse(t.Result));
    }

    private void HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response) {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var contentString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  
        var contentXML = XDocument.Parse(contentString);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Darrel, sorry to get back to late.

Comment: sorry for late reply.I am using POST and right i wanted to accept header.
HttpClient httpClient5 = new HttpClient(handler2);
String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
httpClient5.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded); HttpRequestMessage requestMessage3 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://domain.harvestapp.com/projects");httpClient5.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

Comment: hi @Darrel thanks for your support. I just want to do simple login to Harvest API([link](https://github.com/harvesthq/harvest_api_samples/blob/master/harvest_api_sample.cs)) from WINRT app. but unable to do from my Windows 8 app. hope it make some sense.

Comment: Hello, any other suggestion please. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @user1957642 Can you update your original question to show what request you are trying to make and what is the response you are getting.

Comment: Hi @Darrel, thanks for your time and assistance. I just need to login to the Harvest API [link](https://github.com/harvesthq/harvest_api_samples/blob/master/harvest_api_sample.cs). just want to login to the API. If you see the link i believe you will have more understaing. It sould be very simple but really I have wasted 3 days. Thanks again for your support

Comment: @user1957642  I updated my response with a sample using the Github sample code running in a Win8 store app.  I'm currently getting a HTML response back, but I'm assuming that's because the URL is not pointing to a valid account and the credentials are wrong.

Comment: thanks a lot. all seems to be working fine.  Its much appreciated. I owe you big time mate. Thanks again.